# how to dynamically generate csv error headers

Tags: rythm

I am trying to generate a csv file with errors. My errors object is a List of error objects. Each error object contains id, and message

Now in my CSV file,for eg: if the list contains 2, I need to generate

Message Id1, Message1, Message Id2, Message2.

I am wondering if it is possible to do using rythm template engine.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it will be one line csv file and it should look something like:

```
@args List<ErrorMessage> errors
@for(errors).join(","){@_.getId(),@_.getMessage()}
```

Comment: I think i said it too fast. It worked but all the rows are coming in a single line. Lets say if I have4 records, they are all printing in a single row. Can you please advise what I should do to fix?

Comment: It is one line csv file from your question description, isn't it?

Comment: Headers are on the first row. And all the objects will be placed in individual rows. I have a requirement to show 5 errors for each row. If I hard code the errors headers to errorId1, errorMessage1 ... errorId5, errorMessage5, i am not getting required output if I iterate through the error object with your suggested code.

Comment: can you type your current template code here? I will come up with a solution once I read your code

Comment: Here is my template. Headers are constant. 
@args com.helper.myObj.MyObject myObj 
SKU, Group ID, Locale, Channel ID, Item ID, Status, Message1 ID,  Message1, Message2 ID, Message2, Message3 ID, Message3, Message4 ID, Message4, Message5 ID, Message5

@for(com.helper.myObj.MyObject myObj : myObjects) {
@myObj.getSku(),@myObj.getGroupId(),@myObj.getLocale(), @myObj.getChannelId(), @myObj.getItemId(), @myObj.getOverallStatus(), @for(main.rythm.ErrorObject eo : myObj.getErrObj()).join(","){@eo.getErrId(),@eo.getErrMsg()}
}

Comment: Thank you for the sample. I wonder how my current template is different from what you proposed. can you please let me know. The same solution is printing all objects (in my eg: i have 4 objects as part of myObjects) in one single

Comment: The proposed solution has line breaks. Does it work at all?

Comment: No it didn't work. All records are printing in one row.  I am using IntelliJ with jdk1.7. Not sure if matters.

Comment: Try to take a look at http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/#/editor/ffc1f67d8af44ad3acf37296ea4da7e1. It simulate what should happen in your case, the result rendered are actually break into multiple rows.